# proof $\Vert a\Vert^2\Vert b\Vert^2=\Vert a \times b \Vert^2+\vert a\cdot b\vert^2$

Tags: geometry

$\Vert a\Vert^2\Vert b\Vert^2=\Vert a \times b \Vert^2+\vert a\cdot b\vert^2$, where a and b are vectors

Comment: $1=\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
$$
\| a \times b\|=\|a\| \cdot \| b\| \cdot \sin(\theta) \\
a \cdot b = \|a \|\cdot \| b\| \cdot \cos(\theta)$$

Comment: You have your sine and cosine reversed.

Comment: @Spencer Ty, chch2 fixed it before I could edit. This is what happens when I do not have enough coffeeeee.

Comment: thanks. but why the first equality is true if we define $cos(\theta)=(a\cdot b)/(\Vert a \Vert \Vert b \Vert)$

Comment: @CHENWONG That is one of the basic properties of the cross product. If you did not cover that yet,just write $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3), b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and caculate the norm.

Comment: I get it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\|a \times b\| = |a| |b| \sin \theta,$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a, b.$